# Problem with Navigation (Error: Range Error (index): Index out of range: no indicies are valid:0) when i navigate edit page to detailPage give error

Tags: database, flutter, api, dart, flutter-layout

When i  am update some field then  it updated successfully and redirect on detail Page but it give following error to me when redirect:
RangeError index out of range:no indices are valid:0.
I cannot get what is the problem in my code.Please guide me about it.
I am attaching my code here
**AppointmentDetailEditPage**

```
class AppointmentDetailsEditPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final int aptId;
      final int docID;
      final int staffId;
      final String dTitle;
      final int tNo;
      final String aptExecutive;
    
      AppointmentDetailsEditPage(
          this.aptId,
          this.docID,
          this.staffId,
          this.dTitle,
          this.tNo,
          // this.doctitle,
          //  this.docToken,
          this.aptExecutive);
    
      @override
      _AppointmentDetailsEditPageState createState() =>
          _AppointmentDetailsEditPageState(this.aptId, this.docID, this.staffId,
              this.dTitle, this.tNo, this.aptExecutive);
    }
    
    class _AppointmentDetailsEditPageState
        extends State<AppointmentDetailsEditPage> {
      var paymentMode = ["Online", "Cash", "Cheque"];
    
      String? selectedMode;
      var items = ["Owner", "Tenant", "Agent", "Both"];
    
     
    
      var status = ["Open", "Closed", "Cancel"];
      TextStyle style = const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 6.0);
    
      AppointmentController appointmentController =
          Get.put(AppointmentController());
    
      late Future<Appointment> futureAppointments;
      late final int aptId;
      late final int docID;
      late final int staffId;
    
      late final String dTitle;
      late final int tNo;
      final String aptExecutive;
    
      List<Appointment> aptmnt = [];
    
    
      _AppointmentDetailsEditPageState(
        this.aptId,
        this.docID,
        this.staffId,
        this.dTitle,
        this.tNo,
        this.aptExecutive,
      );
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        futureAppointments =
            AppointmentController.fetchAppointmentsById(this.aptId);
    
        init();
      }
    
      Future init() async {
        print('apt ID $aptId');
    
        final aptmnt = await AppointmentController.fetchAppointments;
        setState(() {
          this.aptmnt = aptmnt as List<Appointment>;
          print(aptmnt);
        });
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
            title: Text('Edit Appointment'),
            // flexibleSpace: LogOut(),
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: BackButtonIcon(),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => AppointmentDetails(
                        aptId, docID, staffId, dTitle, tNo, aptExecutive)))),
          ),
          body:
              //SafeArea(
              Center(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: FutureBuilder<Appointment>(
                    future: futureAppointments,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Form(
                            key: _formKey,
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(
                                        //height: 80.0,
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                          minLines: 1,
                                          maxLines: 3,
                                          readOnly: true,
                                          // autovalidateMode:
                                          //     AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                          inputFormatters: [
                                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(100),
                                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                                RegExp(
                                                    "[,-/ a-z A-Z á-ú Á-Ú 0-9]")),
                                          ],
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                                          controller: docTitleController =
                                              TextEditingController(
                                                  text: '${this.dTitle}'),
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            errorStyle:
                                                const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                            labelText: 'Document Title',
                                            hintText: 'Document Title required',
                                          ),
                                          validator: MultiValidator([
                                            RequiredValidator(
                                                errorText: 'Required*')
                                          ]),
                                        ),
                                      ),
   

    Navigator.of(context).push(
                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                      builder:
                                                          (BuildContext context) =>
                                                              AppointmentDetails(
                                                                  aptId,
                                                                  docID,
                                                                  staffId,
                                                                 
    
                                                                  dTitle,
                                                                  tNo,
                                                                  aptExecutive)));
```

**AppointmentController**

```
Future<Appointment> createAppointment(
  int? aptId,
  int? docId,
  int staffId,
  //String docTitle,
  // String tokenNo,
  String partyName,
  String contactNo,
  String partyType,
  String aptPlace,
  String city,
  int? feesCollected,
  int totalFees,
  String paymentMode,
  String aptDate,
  String aptTime,
  // String aptExecutive,
  String aptStatus,
  String comments,
  // String createdAt,
) async {
  final response = await http.put(
      // Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.134:8080/AtdochubJ-3/appointment/register'),
      Uri.parse('http://3.108.194.111:8080/AtdochubJ-3/appointment/register'

          // 'http://3.108.194.111:8080/AtdochubJ-3/appointment/register'
          ),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        'aptId': aptId,
        'docId': docId,
        'staffId': staffId,
    
        'partyName': partyName,
        'contactNo': contactNo,
        'partyType': partyType,
        'aptPlace': aptPlace,
        'city': city,
        'feesCollected': feesCollected!,
        'totalFees': totalFees,
        'paymentMode': paymentMode,
        'aptDate': aptDate,
        'aptTime': aptTime,
        //'aptExecutive': aptExecutive,
        'aptStatus': aptStatus,

        'comments': comments,
        //  'createdAt': createdAt,
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
   
    return Appointment.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
else{
  throw Exception(' Failed To Create Appointment');
}
```

**AppointmentDetailPage**

```
class AppointmentDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final int aptId;
  final int staff_Id;
  late final int docID;

  final String dTitle;
  final int tNo;
  final String aptExecutive;
  // final String doctitle;
  // final String docToken;

  AppointmentDetails(this.aptId, this.staff_Id, this.docID, this.dTitle,
      this.tNo, this.aptExecutive);

  @override
  _AppointmentDetailsState createState() => _AppointmentDetailsState(
        this.aptId,
        this.staff_Id,
        this.docID,
        this.dTitle,
        this.tNo,
        this.aptExecutive,
      );
}

class _AppointmentDetailsState extends State<AppointmentDetails> {
  AppointmentController appointmentController =
      Get.put(AppointmentController());

  late Future<Appointment> futureAppointments;
  final int aptId;
  final int staff_Id;
  final int docID;
  final String dTitle;
  final int tNo;
  final String aptExecutive;

  _AppointmentDetailsState(this.aptId, this.staff_Id, this.docID, this.dTitle,
      this.tNo, this.aptExecutive);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //  print('detail staff ID $staff_Id');
    //  print('detail doc ID $docId');
    print('apt detail...... $aptId, $dTitle, $tNo, $aptExecutive');
   
    futureAppointments =
        AppointmentController.fetchAppointmentsById(this.aptId);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
        title: Text('Appointment Details'),
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: BackButtonIcon(),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => AppointmentPageFE()))),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Appointment>(
          future: futureAppointments,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(children: [
                SafeArea(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      height: 750,
                      child: SelectionArea(
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text('Document Title: ' + this.dTitle,
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),



Navigator.of(context)
                                            .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (BuildContext
                                                            context) =>
                                                        AppointmentDetailsEditPage(
                                                          this.aptId,
                                                          this.docID,
                                                          this.staff_Id,
                                                          this.dTitle,
                                                          this.tNo,
                                                          this.aptExecutive,
                                                        )),
                                                (Route<dynamic> route) =>
                                                    false);
                                      },
                                    ),
```

Comment: please share all details controller and details screen

Comment: Please do share the error log or stack trace which helps us to find where the issue is

Comment: RangeError index out of range:no indices are valid:0. this error comes when i redirect detail page

Comment: Expected a value of type 'List<Appointment$>', but got one of type '(String) => FutureOr<Iterable<Appointment$>>' this error print or console

Comment: please help me. how to solve this issue